# mysqli escape string additional parameter

Tags: php

Why `mysqli_real_escape_string` is asking additional parameter? In procedural method we must include connection establishment also. Whats logic behind that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're providing database connection link. This is so that you could have multiple MySQL connections at once.

Comment: I hope mysqli_real_escape_string is just a function to safeguard data input (by remove or altering harmful chars). Then what necessary to associate with database link?

Comment: Because it needs to detect database charset. Read the manual.

Answer (score 0):

In certain scenarios, you may want to open several connections and connect to multiple MySQL databases. Explicitly stating the connection link identifier that you want to use allows you to query multiple MySQL databases without worrying about conflicts.

```
//Open connections to two separate databases. For example: DatabaseOne and DatabaseTwo
$databaseOne = mysqli_connect("example.com", "user", "password", "DatabaseOne");
$databaseTwo = mysqli_connect("example.com", "user", "password", "DatabaseTwo");

//Make variable clean for first connection to DatabaseOne
$var= mysqli_real_escape_string($databaseOne, $var);

//QUERY TABLE FROM DATABASE ONE
$res1 = mysqli_query($databaseOne, "SELECT col FROM tableInDatabaseOne WHERE col = '$var'");
//do something with $res1

//QUERY TABLE FROM DATABASE TWO
$res2 = mysqli_query($databaseTwo, "SELECT col FROM tableInDatabaseTwo");
//do something with $res2
```

Comment: I hope mysqli_real_escape_string is just a function to safeguard data input (by remove or altering harmful chars). Then what necessary to associate with database link?